# http handlers does not work in sub virtual directory - images and crsytal report icons not showing in the website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, crystal-reports, dundas

I am having a trouble seeing the charts in my website (using dundas chart and chart.axd) as well as crystal report images (navigation , print button, etc) which uses crystalImageHandeler.aspx

the website shows all this right when running using root level : https:\mywebsite\

however my website had to be implemented in two sub virtual directories for the proxy redirect puspose: so now I have https:\mywebsite\subVirtual_1\subVirtual_2

I am using the web.config in both , and I know the web.config in the subVirtual_2 inherits from the root level. I have already tried putting the handler registration in both web.configs as well as only putting it in the lowest level web.config

can any one help me why still cannot see the charts,images ?using https:\mywebsite\subVirtual_1\subVirtual_2 ?

all this are set up in IIS 7 using .Net 2

Comment: Do you get any errors, like "bobj undefined"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Dundas, but for Crystal there could be several reasons for this issue. Unless you have any error messages like "bobj undefined" the first thing I would try is to copy the aspnet_client folder in the wwwroot directory to the subVurtual_2 directory. If you have a bobj error, please see this [post](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/01/12/how-do-i-resolve-bobj-is-undefined-issue) for detailed instructions on what to do. If neither of these two options work for you, try an http sniffing utility to see where the process is looking for the viewer and go from there. [Charles](http://xk72.com/) and [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) are two excellent utilities.